# Can't evaluate limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the following piece of code to know if it's constant but whenever I run it it just simply shows the formal limit expression as output.
Can someone help me ? Thanks !
[image]

```
In[23]:= Limit[((-0.7379184237636205` - 
      6.190611316875687`*^-18 I) Cos[0.6782329983125268` t] + 
   1.` E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[0.3217670016874732` t] Cos[
     0.6782329983125268` t] - (0.26208157623637957` - 
      6.190611316875687`*^-18 I) E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[0.6782329983125268` t] Cos[1.6782329983125268` t] - 
   0.6215677771527875` E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[0.6782329983125268` t] Sin[
     0.3217670016874732` t] + (0.6528008152946788` - 
      1.82551168470959`*^-18 I) Sin[0.6782329983125268` t] - 
   0.6215677771527875` E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[0.3217670016874732` t] Sin[0.6782329983125268` t] - 
   0.0312330381418914` E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[1.6782329983125268` t] Sin[0.6782329983125268` t] - 
   0.9999999999999998` E^(0.2` t)
     Sin[0.3217670016874732` t] Sin[0.6782329983125268` t] + 
   0.031233038141891403` E^(0.2` t)
     Cos[0.6782329983125268` t] Sin[1.6782329983125268` t] - 
   0.26208157623637957` E^(0.2` t)
     Sin[0.6782329983125268` t] Sin[1.6782329983125268` t]), 
 t -> Infinity]


Out[23]= 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(t \[Rule] \[Infinity]\)]\) \
((-0.737918 - 6.19061*10^-18 I) Cos[0.678233 t] + 
   1. E^(0.2 t)
     Cos[0.321767 t] Cos[
     0.678233 t] - (0.262082 - 6.19061*10^-18 I) E^(0.2 t)
     Cos[0.678233 t] Cos[1.67823 t] - 
   0.621568 E^(0.2 t)
     Cos[0.678233 t] Sin[
     0.321767 t] + (0.652801 - 1.82551*10^-18 I) Sin[0.678233 t] - 
   0.621568 E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.321767 t] Sin[0.678233 t] - 
   0.031233 E^(0.2 t) Cos[1.67823 t] Sin[0.678233 t] - 
   1. E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.321767 t] Sin[0.678233 t] + 
   0.031233 E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.678233 t] Sin[1.67823 t] - 
   0.262082 E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.678233 t] Sin[1.67823 t])
```

Comment: Convert your code to `InputForm` then copy and paste actual code into your question rather than an image of the code. To help you, we need to be able to copy and paste your code into a notebook.

Comment: Plotting the function out to, say, $t=1$, $t=5$, $t=50$, $t=100$, etc. suggests that the limit is infinite.

Comment: @march: Did you read my answer before having posted your comment? The result of my answer contradicts your  guess .

Comment: @user64494. I was too hasty in saying that the limit is infinite.  Actually, it oscillates forever while growing exponentially, and so yes, the limit is indeterminate. My comment was more about how to get a feeling for what the function is doing before using Mathematica to evaluate something complicated.

Comment: Inspection of `Collect[func, Power[E, _], TrigReduce] // Chop` makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

In version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
DiscreteLimit[ FullSimplify[ PowerExpand[ComplexExpand[
Re[Rationalize[((-0.7379184237636205 - 
       6.190611316875687*^-18 I) Cos[0.6782329983125268 t] + 
    1. E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.3217670016874732 t] Cos[
      0.6782329983125268 t] - (0.26208157623637957 - 
       6.190611316875687*^-18 I) E^(0.2 t) Cos[
      0.6782329983125268 t] Cos[1.6782329983125268 t] - 
    0.6215677771527875 E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.6782329983125268 t] Sin[
      0.3217670016874732 t] + (0.6528008152946788 - 
       1.82551168470959*^-18 I) Sin[0.6782329983125268 t] - 
    0.6215677771527875 E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.3217670016874732 t] Sin[
      0.6782329983125268 t] - 
    0.0312330381418914 E^(0.2` t) Cos[1.6782329983125268 t] Sin[
      0.6782329983125268 t] - 
    0.9999999999999998 E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.3217670016874732 t] Sin[
      0.6782329983125268 t] + 
    0.031233038141891403 E^(0.2 t) Cos[
      0.6782329983125268 t] Sin[1.6782329983125268 t] - 
    0.26208157623637957 E^(0.2 t) Sin[
      0.6782329983125268 t] Sin[1.6782329983125268 t]), 0]]]]], 
 t -> Infinity]
```

> Indeterminate

This implies  so does the limit under consideration.

Comment: It also prints "Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD" in 13.2 many times.

Answer (score 0):

Your function contains an oscillating part given by a linear combination of sin and cos multiplied by an exponential factor that increases with t. So for t->Infinity there is no finite limit.